# Creating a new column in an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table to store users and one table to store member fee payments:

**Users**

- Id (int)
- Name (string)

**MemberFeePayments**

- Id (int)
- User (int)
- Year (int)

The "User" column in MemberFeePayment is a reference (foreign key) to the user that have payed the fee. The "Year" column tells which year the user have payed the fee for. If a user has been a member for several years, there will be multiple rows for the user in the MemberFeePayments table.

Now I would like to write an sql query that fetches ALL users. The resulting table should have a column that tells if the users are members in a specific year (which will be provided to the query):

**Result**

- Id (int)
- Name (string)
- IsMember (bool)

What is a good way to accomplish this?

I'm using MySql (5.6).

Comment: Have you tried anything? this can be easily done using `left join`

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: I'm really new to joins :/ I've tried, but the way I do it I only get the users that are members (in the specified year). I want a list of ALL users, but with a column that tells if they are members or not. I bet the solution is simple :)

Comment: -1 for no research and effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if there is only one Fee Payment record per year:

```
SELECT 
    U.Id, U.Name, 
    CASE WHEN M.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS `IsMember`
FROM Users U 
LEFT JOIN MemberFeePayments M ON (U.Id = M.User AND M.Year = 2013)
```

This will work if you have multiple payments in year:

```
SELECT 
    U.Id, U.Name, 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(M.ID) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `IsMember`
FROM Users U 
LEFT JOIN MemberFeePayments M ON (U.Id = M.User AND M.Year = 2013)
GROUP BY U.Id, U.Name;
```

[Here's a link to a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d243/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can do it. So it will lit all the users no matter they are in the MemberFeePayments table or not and will show Yes if they are member for a particular year else No.

```
select
x.Id,
x.Name,
case when x.member is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end as IsMember
from
(
  select
  u.Id,
  u.Name,
  m.User as member 
  from Users u
  left join MemberFeePayments m on m.User = u.Id AND m.year = 2014 

)x
```

OR simply as below without doing the outer select from derived table.

```
select
u.Id,
u.Name,
case when m.User IS NOT NULL THEN  'Yes' else 'No' end as IsMember
from Users u
left join MemberFeePayments m on m.User = u.Id AND m.year = 2014
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39f55d/4)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.Id,a.Name,if(b.id>0,TRUE,FALSE) as ismember FROM USERS a LEFT JOIN MemberFeepayments b ON a.id=b.id
```

check column fields and table name

Comment: guess you ment `left join`, `b` is not defined and it should be `a.id = b.user`

Comment: Pretty much a copy of what I already posted, although the inner join isn't correct - people that have never paid will be excluded, no?

Answer (score -1):

Use `left join`

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.Name,t2.id 
FROM Users t1 
LEFT JOIN MemberFeePayments t2 ON t1.id = t2.user and t2.year = 2014
```

`t2.id` will be null if there are no data in `MemberFeePayments` for that user and year